# Ajax prevents setting jQuery select value? (Django admin)

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm completely perplexed by the behavior of a select box that I am experiencing. I have 2 consecutive `select`s on my page in the django admin, for form (`#id_form`) and then section (`#id_section`). If nothing is selected for the form, the section `select` is disabled. When a form is selected, I use ajax to retrieve the sections of that form to display in the second `select`.

My Ajax/jQuery retrieves and displays the correct sections, but I cannot change the selection.

```
$("#id_form").change(function () {
    var section = $('#id_section');
    section.prop('disabled', $.trim(this.value) === '');

    var eval_form_id = $(this).val();
    if (eval_form_id.length > 0) {
        $.getJSON("/section-filter/" + eval_form_id + "/", function (data) {
            $('#id_section option:not([value=""])').remove();
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                section.append($("<option />").val(value[0]).text(value[1]));
            });
        });
    }
    section.val("1");
}).change();
```

If I  comment out the Ajax portion (or when the empty option is selected for the form), the option "1" is selected, but when the ajax call occurs, it isn't. When I use the debugger in Chrome, the value in the select changes correctly at `section.val("1")`, but for some reason it reverts to the empty choice at the very end of the jQuery.

This is what I don't understand: the jQuery changes the value whether the ajax call occurred or not, but it reverts the value before finishing. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AJAX call happens asynchronously, and only after it finishes it calls your callback function, which fills the select with options.

So the following happens: you start the AJAX call, then change the select's value, then the AJAX call finishes, deletes all the options (including the selected one), and fills the select with new ones.

You should move `section.val("1")` inside the callback function, just after the `$.each` line.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad it was a simple fix. It seems so obvious now that you pointed it out, but it didn't occur to me as an ajax noob.